# How to create a nice add button to list view like in the Weather app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Following these steps:

Open the Weather app.
Right click
Click on places

See that little item with the + symbol?  I want to do something exactly like that, the looks and behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just trying to get some basic ideas about `metro-ui` controls and you are on Release Preview.

When you do right click, the control that's being triggered is called `App Bar`. The "place" button is a `App Bar Command`. Clicking on the button will take you to another page (`HTML` or `XAML`). This page contains a `ListView` control with `GridLayout`. You can dynamically change the `ListView Template` and assign different actions to the `itemInvoke` event.

Here is a quick tutorial for App Bar and commands: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465309.aspx

Here is a quick tutorial for List View control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx